# Is there an @After advice Spring equivalent in Quarkus?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, decorator, cdi, quarkus

In a **Quarkus application**, I want to fire events with the results of a method, and we think the equivalent of an @After advice in Spring, which:

> "runs after the target method is finished, including when the target
> method results in exception. This advice is similar to the finally
> block in Java that it always executes irrespective of the outcome."

But I cannot find the equivalent on Quarkus, I can only use Interceptors/Decorators, which intercepts/modifies the payload on method entry.

Is there anything equivalent, or how would you suggest to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An interceptor can still be used:

```java
@AroundInvoke
Object intercept(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    Object result = context.proceed();
    // do stuff; possibly update or replace result
    return result;
}
```